# Pre-Select of an option in a select not working

Tags: angularjs

I use the following select. Currently, I get empty options in my select on start. To avoid these empty options in angularJS, I want to preselect the first option in the select. But It do not work. I get an 'Cannot read property 'conditions' of undefined'. Thank you for your tips!

**HTML**

```
<select ng-show="rule.field=='Cardiology'" ng-options="c.name as c.name for c in conditions" ng-model="rule.condition" class="form-control input-sm selectCondition"></select>
```

**JS**

```
scope.conditions = [{
        name : 'contains',
}, {
        name : 'doesn´t contain',
}];

$scope.conditions = {type : $scope.conditions[0].value};
```

Comment: It's vague that you're using scope.conditions and $scope.conditions (notice $)

Comment: you have scope.conditions = [{},{}], but then you do $scope.conditions = {type : $scope.conditions[0].value}; it should be $scope.conditions = {type : scope.conditions[0].value};

Comment: [quote from ngOptions Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)
'By default, ngModel watches the model by reference, not value. This is important when binding any input directive to a model that is an object or a collection.' you need to set `$scope.condition = $scope.conditions[anyConditionYouWantToSet]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind value in model to get selected.

Try like this

```
$scope.rule.condition=$scope.conditions[0].value;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It do not work I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'rule' of undefined
    at Scope.compile.scope.changeParameter (angular-query-builder.js:357)
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12345)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14401)
    at angular.js:20541
    at angular.js:23184
    at forEach (angular.js:323)
    at NgModelController.$$writeModelToScope (angular.js:23182)
    at writeToModelIfNeeded (angular.js:23175)
    at angular.js:23169
    at validationDone (angular.js:23097)

Comment: Seriously? Your $scope is not defined? You need to work that out..
The answer does precisely what you want.